# elastic search highlight not working with filter query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I can't get this to highlight for the life of me. It seems like elastic search is broken with regards to highlighting on fields that are mentioned in a filtered clause. The below query just does not highlight. Is this an issue with Elastic? What can I do to make this work?

```
    {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "language": "Austrian"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "standard_analyzed_name",
                  "standard_analyzed_message"
                ],
                "query": "Arnold AND Schwarz"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "sort": [
    {
      "total_interactions": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "standard_analyzed_name": {
        "pre_tags": [
          "<strong>"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
          "</strong>"
        ],
        "fragment_size": 500,
        "number_of_fragments": 1
      },
      "standard_analyzed_message": {
        "pre_tags": [
          "<strong>"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
          "</strong>"
        ],
        "fragment_size": 500,
        "number_of_fragments": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The above query does highlight in elastic search 2.0.0 - Yayyy

Comment: Can you share your mapping and some documents that might be helpful to reproduce your case?

Comment: Thanks, what about your mapping? `curl -XGET localhost:9200/facebook_posts/_mapping/document`

Comment: Here is the data: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/imtiazahmad007/8463cde239399a685f0d/raw/b81f66fd0acd9740f3d9fe66ab0c922403bdcd28/data.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, simply put, you have your `query` and `filter` parts swapped. Your `query_string` should go inside the `query` part and the `term` should go inside the `filter` part, then all will be well and you'll see the highlighted fields.

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "query_string": {
               "fields": [
                  "standard_analyzed_name",
                  "standard_analyzed_message"
               ],
               "query": "arnold"
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "language": "austrian"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 20,
   "sort": [
      {
         "total_interactions": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "highlight": {
      "fields": {
         "standard_analyzed_name": {
            "pre_tags": [
               "<strong>"
            ],
            "post_tags": [
               "</strong>"
            ],
            "fragment_size": 500,
            "number_of_fragments": 3
         },
         "standard_analyzed_message": {
            "pre_tags": [
               "<strong>"
            ],
            "post_tags": [
               "</strong>"
            ],
            "fragment_size": 500,
            "number_of_fragments": 3
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my query should have still worked. Highlight seems to be kind of picky.. Would you be able to elaborate on this a little further?

Comment: That does not return any data.

Comment: With `arnold` and `austrian` both in lowercase, I do get one result and one highlighted field: `"I like <strong>Arnold</strong>"`

Comment: I modified my query. Notice the `query": "Arnold AND Schwarz`. Using the and keyword.  This is a result of an API i'm writing for elastic. Does this query condition still work for you?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is no `Schwarz` in the document about Arnold that you shared earlier.

Comment: Sorry I think I searched for match_all but maybe it was not loaded at the time when I ran that match_all query. Do you need the data again?

Comment: Would be easier to help you with the data, indeed ;)

Comment: Here is the entire data. It was defaulting to size 10 or something so the whole thing didn't come back with match_all without an explicitly larger size. But here you go: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/imtiazahmad007/8463cde239399a685f0d/raw/b81f66fd0acd9740f3d9fe66ab0c922403bdcd28/data.json

Comment: Could you give me the commands you use to load this data to elastic? There is an external program at my end that generates this data from some file. Thanks.

Comment: For `"query": "arnold AND schwarz"` I get the document with my query above

Comment: If I upgrade to elastic 2.0 do you think my original query would wok? Is it that it's simply not a highlight friendly query or something

Comment: I don't understand why you want to have a `query_string` inside a `filter` in the first place. The query as I've modified above works fine, I'm not sure why you don't like it.

Comment: I love your solution actually. The problem is that the query that I pasted is generated from a API that I developed. It would be quite painful to modify the API that generates this non-highlight friendly query. But I guess that's the only option I have left.

Comment: All you have to do is add the `term` to the `filter/and` and the `query_string` to the `query/bool/must` instead. Should be two lines to swap :)

Comment: I'll try to do that, there is a risk that it will break other components but oh well. Thanks for your help Val.

Comment: Thanks, always glad to help!

Comment: just an FYI, we upgraded the server and the query I had is no longer an issue for v 2.0.0. It highlights as expected so thank god no need to change the api implementation. Thank you

Comment: Ok that's good to know, thanks for reporting back as I'm sure it will also help others with a similar issue in the future.

Comment: Just a note, you can specify `pre_/post_ tags` on fields and do not repeat it on every field.